# Using Scrollmagic for horizontal scroll to the right (not left) leaves big white space

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, scrollmagic

I'm using Scrollmagic to have horizontal scrolling. All works fine when things scroll to the left. When I have it scroll to the right, however, after the last image is a big white space.

I am using this in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This is my html, and all the images are the same width:

```
<!-- horizonal scroll left ------->
<div class="wraper">
    <div class="container" id='container2'>


        <img src="img/demobegins.jpg" />
        <div class="caption more-space-right desktop">
            caption 3

        </div>
        

        <img src="img/demo-mayfair-detre-1950.jpg" />
        <div class="caption more-space-right desktop">
            caption 2
        </div>
        

        <img src="img/demo-exposition-buildings-ca1949-upitt.jpg" />
        <div class="caption more-space-right desktop">
            caption 3
        </div>
        

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end horizonal scroll left------->
```

css:

```
.wraper{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container{
  width: 4000px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container2 {

}

.container p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


#container2 img, #container2 .caption {
    float: right;
}

.container .caption {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

jquery:

```
var HorzcontrollerLeft = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var tl2 = new TimelineMax();

var elementWidth2 = document.getElementById('container2').offsetWidth;

var width2 = window.innerWidth - elementWidth2;

var duration2 = elementWidth / window.innerHeight * 100;

var official2 = duration2 + '%';

tl2
.to('#container2', 5, {x: -width, ease: Power0.easeNone});

var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#container2',
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: official2
})
.setPin('#container2')
.setTween(tl2)
.addTo(HorzcontrollerLeft);
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @Zach Saucier: Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: @Zach Saucier: But I still don't see how to scroll right with ScrollTrigger...

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your ScrollTrigger approach.

Comment: @ZachSaucier: It's just the vanilla demo: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/YzygYvM

Comment: For reference, this was [answered on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/27439-scrolltrigger-horizontal-scroll-to-the-right/).